# How to interpret the stats of index usage?

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, index, performance-tuning, azure-sql-managed-instance

**Question**: How do we interpret the stats shown in the diagram below? The stats seem to indicate bad index designing, how can it be improved. I realize this a sort of broad question since it depends on many factors. But in general terms what could be "possible" better index designing choices here?

Ref: [dm_db_index_usage_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

**Remarks**:

1. Both tables do NOT have clustered index
2. Table1 has only one NONCLUSTERED index
3. Table2 has 31 indexes

**My understanding** (By Row 1, 2, 3, 4 below, I mean the rows of the diagram below):

- Row 1: `SELECT * ...` ran on table1. Optimizer did not find index to be useful here
- Row 2: Key column of index idx_table1 was used in predicate (WHERE clause etc.). Optimizer used quite a few seeks. But still had to scan the table a lot to search for the column values used in SELECT statement
- Row 3: Despite the fact that Table2 has 31 indexes , none was used beause: Either indexed columns were not in the predicate (WHERE clause, etc.), or `SELECT * ...` was run. Hence Key lookup was also heavily used to find values of output columns
- Row 4: Indexed column(s) were used in the predicate. But optimizer still decided to use table scans as better choice

| Table | Table_Size | IndexName | IndexType | IndexSize | SeeksCount | ScansCount | LookupsCount | UpdateCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Table1 | 11GB | NULL | HEAP | 12.4GB | 0 | 1185 | 1 | 0 |
| Table1 | 11GB | idx_table1 | NONCLUSTERED | 12.4GB | 9 | 485 | 0 | 0 |
| Tble2 | 5GB | NULL | HEAP | 14.2GB | 0 | 23 | 20 | 0 |
| Tble2 | 5GB | idx_table2 | NONCLUSTERED | 14.2GB | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

> The stats seem to indicate bad index designing, how can it be improved. I realize this a sort of broad question since it depends on many factors.

One primary factor are the predicates of your queries themselves. Without seeing your queries, there's not much meaningful suggestions that can be made. Feel free to add the main queries your indexes were designed for to your Post, for further detailed assistance.

> Both tables do NOT have clustered index

This is *probably* a problem. It is rare a table shouldn't have a clustered index, especially if it's `SELECT`ed against in any meaningful way. The clustered index persists the actual table itself sorted on the index keys. It can help most types of queries. Without one, the data is stored in a *random* order in the heap. Typically, only staging tables that are used for only `INSERT`s and `DELETE`s are ones that *may* not need a clustered index.

> Table2 has 31 indexes

This is *probably* also a problem. 31 indexes on a single table (especially without a clustered index) sounds unreasonable. You should only keep a reasonable number of indexes with a reasonable number of fields on each table. I use 5 by 5 as a loose guideline. Roughly up to five indexes on a table, with roughly up to five columns defined in each index. The more indexes you have on a table, the longer it'll take DML (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`) statements to run, because each nonclustered index is a copy of the table data for the columns defined in them.

---

Aside from all of that, for the index results you've provided, almost no seeks are being done which is an indication that they're likely poorly defined. If you add your queries, you should also add the index definitions themselves.

Answer (score 1):

J.D. Posted many good points. I want to add some about your interpretations (the "My understanding" section):

We don't have your table definitions, nor do we have your queries. Also, we don't have the query that you ran against sy.dm_db_index_physical_stats. Anyhow:

Your Row 2 means that you only had 9 seeks in the index. The index *might* have covered the query (no lookup in the heap), we can't say that looking at that row alone. The scans for row 2 doesn't mean table scan. It means index scan (look at each page for the index, without going to the heap).

Row 3. These 31 indexes *were* used, at least 20 times since you have 20 lookups. They might have been used more if they covered the query (no lookup in the heap), we can't say by that row alone.

Row 4. We can't say anything about included columns judging by this row alone. We do know that the index was scanned twice (with or without lookups after), though.